Following redirects on Service creation with Apache CXF
I'm creating a Service passing an URL that may return 302 Found. How can I instruct CXF to follow the redirects at the Service creation?
Already tried setting a HTTPClientPolicy as an extension on the default Bus but without success.
public class Foo extends Service {}

URL url = ...
QName qName = ...

Foo foo = new Foo(url, qName);


I'm currently using the URL from the Location header. Luckily the server accepts connection directly to the actual destination

conigure httpconduit along with setting maxredirects
set up httpclientproxy
